# Is it efficient to compress binary data from canonical Huffman?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, binary, compression, file-storage

I am trying to learn compression algorithms using python ,so I was wondering that is it effective to use run length encoding or delta encoding on my final stream of binary data ('1011') that I get after canonical huffman? right now I am converting my binary data to bytes and storing it in a file, is there more efficient way to store my data ?

Comment: `compress binary data` is (too) broad. `binary data [from] canonical huffman` is not - if you do modelling and coding separately, modelling is done *before* coding.

Comment: @greybeard ok, I am doing burrow wheeler transform and move to front encoding before Huffman. Compression ratio is  around 70%, is there a way to improve it? Coz I read that lz77 is used with Huffman to get good results, but In my case there is only 0.5% improvement but it just increases time by huge margin. So in short what else can I do with my setup + I have this thought that is it possible to compress a string of just 1&#39;s and 0&#39;s without any generation of lookup table?

Comment: So do you just want to improve the compression ratio a bit or do you have to keep using canonical Huffman? Can you use something that's closer to the entropy limit, like range coding or ANS?

Comment: @harold thanks, I haven't heard about ANS but I will try it instead of Huffman and see if there is any improvement. And honestly I don't really know how to derive entropy limit of an algorithm but I will look it up, I am still a student who is just interested in compression algorithm.

Comment: You seem to be through with the basics. It may be time to write down *what you want to achieve* and have a look at what others did/do to achieve same (or similar): *State of the Art*. *If and when* you are dissatisfied with the results, or have a novel idea, roll your own. Don't waste time on compressors you don't have a working decompressor for.

Comment: @greybeard ,oki doki thanks !